# Let V be an infinite dimensional vector space over a division ring D. The Set F={θ:V→V: Im(θ) is a finite dimensional subspace of V} is a simple ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, ideals, semi-simple-rings, division-ring

I have been able to prove that F is a proper ideal of End(V) but however stuck to show that F is a simple ring. My idea is to start with a two sided ideal of F, I assuming I≠0, then using a nonzero element of I, I want to show that every element of F is in I by some suitable left, right multiplication. But however I am not able to find such multipliers! Please help by providing some way to prove this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related to (?) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238044/the-set-of-all-finite-rank-operators-forms-a-simple-ring-and-contained-in-every